# Div table float

Tags: css

i have div tag like this with 3 tables inside.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>ABC</td><td>ABC</td></tr>
    </table>


    <table>
        <tr><td>XYZ</td><td>XYZ</td></tr>
    </table>

     <table>
        <tr><td>LMN</td><td>LMN</td></tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

The output is

ABC ABC 
XYZ XYZ 
LMN LMN

How can I change to something like this?

```
ABC ABC         XYZ XYZ       LMN LMN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are block level by default, make them inline.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display
- http://jsfiddle.net/3W8bb/

**Example**

```
table {
  display: inline-block;
  /** this works too */
  display: inline-table
}​
```

You can also make them float, as suggested by @j08691

```
table { float: left }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could float the tables left and set a margin on their right side like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rBbzQ/)**

```
​table{
    float:left;
    margin-right:80px;
}
```